# What is a default generic app in CentOS 7 to monitor UPS battery over USB?

Tags: linux, centos, backup, battery, ups

I installed an UPS battery that is not a well known brand, but it has an USB; Other generic UPS monitoring apps on windows can find it and read battery level and other data even without manually installing a driver for it.

In CentOS 7, what is the most common / generic app to monitor an UPS battery over USB? I want o use simplest method that maybe comes included with CentOS, and only use branded software if needed, e.g I seen APC has `apcupsd` but I assume this might only work with theirs UPS, even if it works with this one, maybe there is a more generic default app for this in CentOS ?!

What I want to accomplish is to run a command and get battery level from it, while installing as little extra dependencies as possible.

Comment: NUT (Network UPS Tools) is a common tool and supports lots of UPSes; https://networkupstools.org/stable-hcl.html

Comment: NUT is also in EPEL7 (as the `nut` package).

Comment: Thanks. I also came across that one, I will give it a try.